# overlapping title over text css issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://www.kalematconsulting.com/#news

It seems to be an issue in mobile view when i go the news section

The title 'Unstrategy and the last mile of change' seems to overlap the text below 'By Admin | Date | Category

[image]

I have tried inspecting element and playing around but cannot figure this one out. I can add in custom css on this wp theme if someone can help me?

Comment: if you supply the HTML and CSS then it'll be easier to debug and give specific advice. Too many things could be going on to solve from just an image

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @KevPrice  - The website is built on Wordpress, I think you would need access to backend? The url is in the original post if you are able to debug in browser?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed No you need to post relevant code to identify problem

Comment: @WaqarAhmed instead of requiring someone to trawl through irrelevant code on your website. I am suggesting that you copy and paste the relevant sections of code from your website into your question - i.e. you do the finding of the code in your browser and paste it here. Html and Css

Answer (score 0):

you get this problem because of this code.

```
.kalemat-post .fusion-alignleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
```

you have to do little HTML and CSS edit.

move this html tag `<div class="fusion-meta-info"></div>` after `<h2>` tag which contains news title and before this tag `<div class="fusion-post-content-container"></div>`
Next change your CSS like this.

```
.kalemat-post .fusion-alignleft {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @ IsuruAb
looking at the HTML

<div class="fusion-meta-info"></div> is already past the news title <h2> tags

making the css edit as you suggested pushes the line meta tag info below the blog excerpt

Comment: Sorry I havent been able to do it as i dont know how :(

Comment: @WaqarAhmed please add the code of news section .then i can show you